# Spring framework Tomcat LoadTimeWeaving

Tags: tomcat, jpa, lazy-loading, eclipselink, load-time-weaving

I am using tomcat as my webserver and would like to use the `fetch = FetchType.lazy` annotation for all my @OneToOne annotations but spring reverts my lazy settings give me eclipselink warnings :

```
Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [student] for the entity class [class org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Registration] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

What do i have to do to tomcat to get weaving working so i can use lazy fetching or is there any other alternatives to lazy load relationships. I am having huge performance problems?

I am now attempting to add loadtime weaving, i have added both spring-instruments.jar and spring-aspects.jar to my tomcat/lib and after adding the global `<context:load-time-weaver/>` to my applicationContext.xml file, i get an

```
ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285684/cant-understand-eclipselink-warning or hitting this bug https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9081

Comment: That SO question and the eclipselink resource provided give no clear direction as to where things need to go (spring.instruments.jar) and the updates to context.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using static weaving instead, see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

It is possible to get weaving working in Spring.  I would recommend starting with one of the Spring tutorials outside of Tomcat, and slowly add complexity until you have it working inside Tomcat.

Comment: i have taken a look at this documentation and it is really hard to follow (configure) properly. How do i know i have enabled static weaving properly, is there a github repository example project that has an example using tomcat as the web server?

Comment: Do i have to if i use static weaving always run the command line argument when i build and run the project

Comment: Yes, you must run the task on your jar and use the weaved jar it outputs.

Comment: cant this be put in my project once to utilize eclipse as my run,build and deploy tool. I tried adding the maven-ant plugin and adding the specified task but nothing seems to work and the lazy settings get reverted